# Unreachable objects on the stack cannot be garbage collected

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, jvm

Against my expectations, the following program

```
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class StackTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object object1 = new Object();
    Object object2 = new Object();
    List<Object> objects = Arrays.asList(object1, object2);

    WeakReference<Object> ref1 = new WeakReference<>(object1);
    WeakReference<Object> ref2 = new WeakReference<>(object2);

    for (Object o : objects) {
      System.out.println(o);
    }
    objects = null;

    object1 = null;
    object2 = null;

    System.gc();
    System.gc();
    System.gc();

    System.out.println("ref1: " + ref1.get());
    System.out.println("ref2: " + ref2.get());
  }
}
```

still prints out

```
ref1: java.lang.Object@15db9742
ref2: java.lang.Object@6d06d69c
```

meaning `object1` and `object2` are not GC-ed.

However, when removing the `for` loop from the program, those objects can be GC-ed and the program prints.

```
ref1: null
ref2: null
```

Moving the `for` loop to a separate method has the same effect: the objects are GC-ed at the end of the program.

What I suspect is happening is that that `for` loop stores those objects on the stack, and does not remove them afterwards. And since the object is still present on the stack, it cannot be GC-ed.

Looking at the byte code (which I am really not that good at) seems to support this hypothesis:

```
53: invokeinterface #6,  1            // InterfaceMethod java/util/List.iterator:()Ljava/util/Iterator;
58: astore        6
60: aload         6
62: invokeinterface #7,  1            // InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.hasNext:()Z
67: ifeq          90
70: aload         6
72: invokeinterface #8,  1            // InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.next:()Ljava/lang/Object;
77: astore        7
79: getstatic     #9                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
82: aload         7
84: invokevirtual #10                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
87: goto          60
```

I see `astore` commands, but I couldn't spot a place in the byte code where those are removed from the stack again.

However, I have two issues with my theory:

- From what I understood from that byte code, I would have expected that `object1` is removed from the stack (overwritten by `object2`), and only the last object accessed in the loop (`object2`) would not be GC-ed.
- Changing the `for` loop to

  ```
  for (Object o : objects) {
    System.out.println(o);
    o = null;
  }
  ```

  doesn't change the output of the program. I would have thought that that would clear that reference to the object on the stack.

**Question**: anybody has a solid theory on why that `for`-loop ensures that those objects cannot be GC-ed ? My theory has a few gaping holes in them.

**Context**:
This problem was encountered in a unit tests which we use to detect memory leaks, based on the Netbeans method [`NBTestCase#assertGC`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-nbjunit/org/netbeans/junit/NbTestCase.html#assertGC-java.lang.String-java.lang.ref.Reference-). This `assertGC` method will fail when an object is still referenced on the heap or on the stack.

In our test, we have code like

```
@Test
public void test(){
  List<DisposableFoo> foos = ...;

  doStuffWithFoo(foos);

  List<WeakReference<DisposableFoo>> refs = ...;

  for(DisposableFoo foo : foos){
    disposeFoo(foo);
  }

  foos = null;
  assertGC(refs);
}
```

which kept on failing, until we removed the `for`-loop.

We already have a workaround (move the `for`-loop to a separate method), but I would like to understand why our original code does not work.

Comment: Just because you call `System.gc` but not mean that GC has happended - but I am sure you know that

Comment: @ScaryWombat: I know. The real code fills up the whole heap a few times combined with calling `System.gc` a few times. I removed that from this program to keep it simple. Note that I can consistently reproduce the problem with the posted code, and removing the for loop consistently makes it work.

Comment: what happens if you use a traditional loop

Comment: @ScaryWombat a traditional for loop works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you still have a list iterator on the stack, and that list iterator has a reference to the original list. That's keeping the list alive just as if you'd never set `objects` to null.

An iterator has to keep a reference to the original collection, so that it can request the *next* item etc. For a regular `Iterator<E>` it could *potentially* set its internal reference to `null` once `hasNext()` had returned false, but for a list iterator even that's not the case, as you can move in both directions within a list iterator.

Comment: That sounds like a solid theory. The fact that it works when I call `objects.clear()` before calling `objects = null` confirms this theory.

Comment: You mean once `hasNext()` has returned `false`?

Comment: He who dares, wins!

Comment: In principle, the `Iterator` is unreachable as it is factually unused in the subsequent code, so it is allowed to get collected, but this does not happen with interpreted code, as with the `main` method of such a simple test program. For compiled/optimized code, there are usually no such issues, unused objects could get collected, even if local variables referencing them are still in scope.

Comment: @Holger: Yup, agreed.

Answer (score 1):

Change your for loop and then try again

```
for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++)
{
    Object o = objects.get(i);
    System.out.println(o);
}
```

Comment: That indeed works. But I already have a workaround. My question is really why my construct does not work ... I am failing to understand why the `for` loop ensures that those objects cannot be GC-ed.

Comment: Glad it worked. The next part I am figuring out now. I will update my answer once I reach to any conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Apart form using a traditional loop, you could `wrap` your `for-loop` so that it goes out of scope and gets collected

```
{
for (Object o : objects) {
  System.out.println(o);
}
}
```

the generated iterator stuff would not get cleared out until it goes out of scope

Comment: I think the compiler will optimize away that extra scoping and the result would be same .

Comment: Did not know the compiler would change scope.  If the above doesn't work, then surely a `try-finally` block would

Comment: @Timothy: there is no scoping in the compiled code at all. Conceptually, the iterator would be out of scope after the loop anyway, even without the curly braces, but as long as no new local variable reuses its slot, the reference is dangling in the stack frame.